# Eigenvalues of a Linear Transformation Homework assistance

Tags: linear-algebra

A question on my homework in "Linear Algebra II" I've just been taught about eigenvalues.

T is a linear transformation with the characteristic polynomial: $ p_{T}=-t(t^2-1)(t^2-4)$
it is correct to assert that:

A. $\ p_{T}=p_{T^2}$

B. $\ T^2 $ has 5 distinct eigenvalues

C. $T$ is invertible and $ p_{T^{-1}} = -t(t^2-1)(t^2 -\frac{1}{4})$

D. $ T^2-4I $ has 4 eigenvalues and is not diagonalizable

E. $ T^3-T $ is diagonalizable and has $p_{T^3-T}=-t^3(t-6)(t+6)$

I can tell that A is wrong (cuz $T(u)=\lambda u$ so $ T^2(u)=T(T(u))=\lambda^2 u$ for u and $\lambda$ eigenvector and eigenvalue) and C is wrong cuz $\dim V(0) = 1$ so $\dim \ker(T) = 1$ so T isn't invertible, but I'm pretty clueless for the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with (A) and (C), although I think you should be clearer about the reason for (A). (For example, your reasoning implies that $2^2 = 4$ must be an eigenvalue of $T^2$, but this is not a root of $p_T$.)

(B) The eigenvalues of $T$ are the roots of its characteristic polynomial, so:

> The only eigenvalues of $T$ are $0$, $\pm 1$, $\pm 2$. But the eigenvalues of $T^2$ are the squares of eigenvalues of $T$, so there are three distinct, not five.

(D) The eigenvalues of $T^2$ are the squares of eigenvalues of $T$, hence:

> They are $0$, $1$, and $4$. The eigenvalues of $T^2 - 4 I$ are just these decreased by $4$, i.e. $-4$, $-3$, and $0$. At any rate, there aren't four.

(E) The eigenvalues of $T^3$ are the cubes $\lambda^3$ of the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $T$, and similarly the eigenvalues of $T^3 - T$ are given by $\lambda^3 - \lambda$, hence:

> The eigenvalues of $T^3 - T$ are then $0^3 - 0 = 0$, $1^3 - 1 = 0$, $(-1)^3 - (-1) = 0$, $2^3 - 2 = 6$, and $(-2)^3 - (-2) = -6$. This matches up with the given characteristic polynomial.

Comment: the eig of $T$ are not $0,1,4$